# Is AncestryDNA match of 2,063 cM a half sibling?

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

I am new to AncestryDNA and my results came back with my top match having 2,063 centimorgans out of 62 segments saying close family.

Would this be a half-sibling?

The match is a few years older than me.

Answer (score 5):

[The Shared cM Project 3.0 tool v4 suggests these possible relationships for 2,063 centimorgans](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/2063):

[image]

I think the age difference of just a few years between you and this person lets us rule out grandparent to grandchild and great aunt/uncle to great niece/nephew.

2,063 is considered a little low for full siblings because they normally fall in the 2,209–3,384 range.

That leaves aunt/uncle to niece/nephew or half siblings.

If you are confident from other evidence that neither of your parents had an unknown (to you) full sibling who was much younger than themselves then that leaves the most likely explanation being that you are half siblings.